# What's the technical explanation for custom bokeh shapes?

Tags: bokeh, shaped-bokeh

Simply putting a heart shaped cut-out in front of the lens

[image]

turns this

[image]

into this

[image]

How does that happen? What's the optics behind this phenomenon?

Comment: This is related to why the aperture impacts bokeh shape and is also why you have to use a wide enough aperture.  The bokeh shapes comes from whatever portion of the lens limits the size of the entrance pupil (the front of the lens) visible to the sensor.