# Besides mirror lenses, what can cause ring-shaped bokeh?

Tags: bokeh, shaped-bokeh

A couple of images in a question about [how to create a 'medieval look'](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/97686/75526) appear to have **ring-shaped bokeh.**

- [Catadioptric (mirror) lenses](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/94729/75526) can cause similarly shaped bokeh, but these images do not look like they were taken from a tremendous distance with a 400-600mm lens (the typical focal length of mirror lenses).
- [Another question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/76205/75526) describes similar shapes in the *viewfinder* of a camera, but the recorded image was not affected.

**Besides mirror lenses, what else could cause the ring-shaped bokeh in these photos?**

[image]
[image]

**Notes**

- Regarding [JindraLacko's answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/99686/75526), I find it unbelievable that photographer put stickers in the center of their lenses to achieve this effect. I tried briefly obstructing the center of a lens to see what it would do, and the effect is quite different from the one seen in the sample images.

Comment: related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/50108/35348

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This bokeh effect is known as (soap) **bubble bokeh.** Along with a "glowing" look, this type of bokeh is seen in lenses that have **over-corrected spherical aberration.** It is associated with **[Cooke Triplet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooke_triplet)** lenses, which have three elements in three groups. Myer-Optik Trioplan lenses, such as the 100mm F2.8, are particularly known for their bubble bokeh.

[image: Cooke Triplet]

This image, taken with a Steinheil-Munchen Cassarit 50mm f/2.8, demonstrates both bubble bokeh and glow.

[image: bubble bokeh and glow]

**Further reading:**

- [The cult of bokeh, soap bubbles, and a cheap Meyer Optik Trioplan lens](http://sjp.id.au/adapted-lenses/meyer-optik-trioplan-lens/)
- [Trioplan 100mm f/2.8 Rebirth will Bring ‘Soap Bubble’ Bokeh to Modern Cameras](https://petapixel.com/2015/07/10/trioplan-100mm-f2-8-rebirth-will-bring-soap-bubble-bokeh-to-modern-cameras/)
- [The Legend And the Bubble Bokeh. Review of the Meyer Optik Goerlitz Trioplan 100mm f/2.8](https://fujilove.com/the-legend-and-the-bubble-bokeh-review-of-the-meyer-optik-goerlitz-trioplan-100mm-f2-8/)
- [Markus Keinath: Soap Bubble Bokeh Lenses](http://www.4photos.de/test/Soap-Bubble-Bokeh-Lenses.html)

Answer (score 10):

The doughnut bokeh of catadioptric ("mirror") lenses is not caused by the rear mirror or long focal length, but by the obstruction (front mirror actually) on the front element.

You can achieve it with any lens if you put a round sticker on the front lens. Or better: on a clear (e. g. UV) filter in front of it.

With a little practice you could even achieve a heart or star shaped bokeh.

Comment: The ring/donut shape bokeh is usually considered undesirable.  Would someone try to create it intentionally, as you describe?

Comment: Yup, quite often. Do a quick search for "bokeh rubinar" (a commonly used catadioptric lens) on Flickr to see what I mean...

Comment: @JindraLacko Rubinar is basically an English transliteration of the Russian word for "mirror lens."

Comment: @xiota "usually considered undesirable" is almost an opposite to "always undesirable" in art :)

Comment: @MichaelC not exactly. Rubinar is just a brand name of Soviet mirror lenses. USSR being USSR, there were no other brands, but this doesn't make it a generic Russian word, just like "Aeroflot" doesn't mean "an airline".

Comment: @IMil I suppose you insist that Kleenex and facial tissue aren't the same thing, either? "Aeroflot" may not be a generic Russian language word for airline, but in the USSR, there was only one Soviet based airline and it *was* Aeroflot, so Aeroflot was ***THE*** Russian airline. Similarly, *Rubinar* was ***THE*** Soviet mirror lens.

Comment: @MichaelC well there's a thin line between a monopoly brand and a generic word. I am positive that "Aeroflot" wasn't treated as a generic word for an airline, but I wasn't much of an amateur photographer in the Soviet era, so can't be sure whether Rubinar made the grade. What makes me doubt this is that despite Rubinar being the only photographic lens of the type, mirror lenses were (and are) widely used in telescopes, named differently.